# Determine first year of minimum consecutive year range and count of consecutive years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given the following table,

```
 PersonID     Year
---------- ----------
1          1991
1          1992
1          1993
1          1994
1          1996
1          1997
1          1998
1          1999
1          2000
1          2001
1          2002
1          2003
2          1999
2          2000
...        ...
```

Is there a way with a SQL select query to get the first year of the most recent range of consecutive years meeting a minimum number, as well as the total consecutive years? In this case, for 4 year minimum, for personID 1, it would return 1996 and 8.

This will be joined to another table on personID, so the personID is not specific.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two CTEs to create row number groupings allows you to group by PersonID and display all personIDs that it applies to:

```
Declare @MinimumConsecutiveYears int=4

;With YearGroupings as (
    Select
        PersonID
        ,year
        ,row_number() over(partition by personid order by year asc) rown
    From @years
)
, ConsecutiveYears as (
    Select 
        PersonID
        ,min(year) as MinYear
        ,count(rown) as ConsecutiveYears
        ,row_number() over(partition by PersonID order by count(rown) desc) rown
    From YearGroupings
    Group By PersonID,year-rown
    Having Count(rown)>@MinimumConsecutiveYears
)
Select PersonID,MinYear,ConsecutiveYears
From ConsecutiveYears
Where Rown=1
```

Alternatively, without CTEs:

```
Declare @MinimumConsecutiveYears int=4

Select
    PersonID
    ,year
    ,row_number() over(partition by personid order by year asc) rown
Into #YearGroupings
From #years

Select 
    PersonID
    ,min(year) as MinYear
    ,count(rown) as ConsecutiveYears
    ,row_number() over(partition by PersonID order by count(rown) desc) rown
Into #ConsecutiveYears 
From YearGroupings
Group By PersonID,year-rown
Having Count(rown)>@MinimumConsecutiveYears

Select PersonID,MinYear,ConsecutiveYears
From #ConsecutiveYears
Where Rown=1
```

Comment: Any way to do this without CTE? Also, I won't know the personID ahead of time... updated the question to include "This will be joined to another table on personID, so the personID is not specific."

Comment: Updated answer to have a version without CTEs! This query already returns all PersonIDs having count(*)>@MinimumConsecutiveYears.

Comment: Selected answer is the one without CTEs

Answer (score 3):

You can create [islands of years](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) in the cte and check your conditions:

```
declare @PersonId int = 1, @cnt int = 4

;with cte_numbered as (
      select
            PersonID,
            [Year],
            row_number() over(partition by PersonID order by [Year]) as rn
      from Table1
), cte_grouped as (
  select
       PersonID, min([Year]) as [Year], count(*) as cnt
  from cte_numbered
  group by PersonID, [Year] - rn
)
select top 1 *
from cte_grouped 
where PersonId = @PersonId and cnt >= @cnt
order by [Year] desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd463/23)</kbd>**

You also could do something more optimized, like this

```
declare @PersonId int = 1, @cnt int = 4

;with cte_numbered as (
      select
            PersonID,
            [Year],
            row_number() over(partition by PersonID order by [Year]) as rn
      from Table1
      where personId = @personId
), cte_grouped as (
  select
      row_number() over(partition by [year] - rn order by year) as cnt, year
  from cte_numbered
)
select top 1 cnt, year - cnt + 1
from cte_grouped
where cnt >= @cnt
order by [Year] desc, cnt desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd463/24)</kbd>**

Comment: Any way to do this without CTE? For large data sets, this takes a long time.

Comment: Have you tried second approach. It should be faster. I'm far from computer now, but I'll check tomorrow how it could be improved

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the second approach, and it asks for the personID in the CTE, however, I am joining the `select top 1 ...` part to another table, so won't have access to a personID for the CTE.

Comment: well you could create table-valued function with parameters. But you can easily take PersonId out from cte also and use it as a filter (you also have to use it in `over` clause in second cte

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @minnumber int
set @minnumber = 4

declare @personid int
set @personid = 0

select orig.[PersonID], min(orig.[Year]) as FirstYear ,count(*) as TCYears
from --add rownumber, sorted by year column
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (Partition by [PersonID] ORDER BY [Year]) AS Row,*
        from Table1
    where PersonID = @personid
) orig
where orig.PersonID = @personid
and orig.Row > @minnumber --
group by orig.PersonID
```

Comment: I won't know the personID ahead of time... updated the question to include "This will be joined to another table on personID, so the personID is not specific."